# What were the policy objectives sought to be achieved by California’s proposition 47?

Tags: united-states, crime, referendum, california

Prop 47 modified the status of shoplifting under a certain value threshold from a felony into a misdemeanour for the first offence. What was the objective and impetus for doing this?

What were the main reasons for supporting this proposition and what were the main motivations for opposing it, or for now wanting to repeal it?

I wasn’t intending to create a misleading depiction of the law, and more information about it is available here: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/prop-47-theft-california/

Comment: A lot of critical details about prop 47 have been left out such as it changes the punishment for crimes based on the severity. Specifically it changes theft when the value is under $950 when other criteria are also met. https://www.verifythis.com/article/news/verify/crime-verify/california-prop-47-shoplifting-950-fact-check/536-4d1de58e-bf47-4ede-8c2f-b4d0c1788b86

Comment: Can’t include every detail of everything. But Please Feel free to edit and add any missing details you might feel are critical.

Comment: As the person asking the question it is up to you to include some basic details about what you are asking and not make it appear to be doing something it isn't. As I pointed out prop 47 does not turn shoplifting from a felony to a misdemeanor. It changes what theft is charged at based on the value of the items stolen.

Comment: Well your link doesn’t work in my country.

Comment: You should be able to do a google search and find more information on California Prop 47 and what it actually does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong, at a surface level, with wikipedia's [Support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_California_Proposition_47#Support) section?

> The measure was endorsed by the editorial board of The New York Times, which praised it as a way to reduce overcrowding in the state's prisons.[12] It was also endorsed by the editorial board of the Los Angeles Times, which wrote that the measure was a "good and timely measure that can help the state make smarter use of its criminal justice and incarceration resources."[13] The American Civil Liberties Union also supported the measure and donated $3.5 million to support it.[14]
>
> Prominent individual supporters included Jay-Z and **Newt Gingrich.**[15]

To requote from wikipedia on what 47 did:

> It recategorized some nonviolent offenses as misdemeanors, rather than felonies, as they had previously been categorized.

That [Gingrich](https://www.latimes.com/opinion/op-ed/la-oe-0917-gingrich-prop--47-criminal-justice-20140917-story.html) ref is **intriguing**

> Imagine you have the power to decide the fate of someone addicted to heroin who is convicted of petty shoplifting.
>
> **How much taxpayer money would you spend to put that person in prison — and for how long?** Is incarceration the right form of punishment to change this offender’s behavior?

Wow, precisely what I was going to give as motivation.  Felonies tend to mean long jail terms, at tax payer expense.  For minor crimes, is that a good outcome for society as a whole?  The taxpayer?  The now-felon, who after sitting in jail will face reinsertion issues?

Gingrich and me agree on something, my head spins (this was in 2014, with the opiate crisis he might have changed tack).

Did you read the wiki page before asking?

Comment: Similar logic can be used to reduce the penalty for minor drug offenses, but I wonder if Gingrich would have supported that. If I were cynical I'd suspect that there's some racial bias -- I'll bet lots of minor shoplifting is done by white women.